# Windows Offline Application

Tags: wpf, windows, asp.net-web-api, offline

We are developing a windows application using WPF, ASP.NET WebAPI & SQL server. For presentation layer, we are using WPF. Data will  be stored in SQL database server. All the data communication between client and server is via Web API. In between, we have a facade layer which plays communication between Web API and WPF.

Customer wants this application as offline version for some users who has very limited internet connection.

I mean, users can enter data without internet connection. When user is connected with internet, all the data should be moved to server.

Please share your idea. If anybody done this, please tell us how to do that.

If my question is not clear, or if you need more details on this, I am ready to explain more in detail.

Comment: Your customer need to understand that not everything can be offline or you will need to setup server part on client place.

Comment: In some cases it can be easiest way to solve all problems, just install everything on client side and then use something to merge data.